# How to force at least one term from a list in a full text search in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I can't figure out a specific full text search in MongoDB. I can't found in MongoDB documentation a way to force at least one term from a list like I can do with + sign in MySQL. For example in MySQL I cant define: `"+green +(red blue)"` which select all the rows that contain `"green" AND ("red" OR "blue")` in some of the indexed columns. Note that if some row only contains `green` it won't be selected. There is a "similar" behavior in MongoDB but it doesn't actually work like I need. Let me cite the [official documentation example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases):

```
For example, passed a $search string:

"\"ssl certificate\" authority key"
The $text operator searches for the phrase "ssl certificate" and ("authority" or "key" or "ssl" or "certificate" )
```

So I created the collection **palette** to proof the concept:

```
db.palette.insertMany([
    {colors: "green,black"}, 
    {colors: "green,red"}, 
    {colors: "green,blue"}
])
```

Then I created a text index:

```
db.palette.createIndex({colors: "text"})
```

Note that MongoDB firstly splits the string values by the comma internally in order to index words, I even checked that using `db.palette.validate()` information. Finally I tried to search with the following string:

```
db.palette.find({$text: {$search: "\"green\" red blue"}})
```

I need to retrieve only second and third document but the result includes the first one too (`"green,black"`). I guess it's because of the MongoDB rule described above: `"green" AND ("red" OR "blue" OR "green")` so the last condition is always `true`. Just to test a different schema I splitted `colors` field into `color1` and `color2` then created a compound text index but the result was the same.

so: Is there any way in MongoDB to make the query that I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I wrote to MongoDB guys. The answer from them:

*This feature request is being tracked in [SERVER-22583](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22583). Please feel free to vote for it and watch it for updates.*

So there is currently no way to do what I need :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex functionality for this query. For example:

```
db.palette.find({colors:{$in:[/green.*red/,/green.*blue/]}})
```

docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Comment: Thanks @Moi but I am enforced to solve the problem using full text search only. The real problem is a text search over more than 40 fields so I just reduced the problem asking in a more simple way, just a simple example with colors.